# How to update/make changes to my server application without service down?

Tags: c#, .net, server

I have an application running on a server which handles users data, I am making changes to the code base from time to time when I want to update it I must cut the service of connected clients, is there some tips/workflow or things to consider to make things better. like making the old version merge with the updated one. I know it's a silly question maybe but I am working on a solution and I need some advice from you. (Application written in C#)

I am thinking of using UNIX sockets to hand data to the updated version when it detects it, But I thought it would be wise if I ask first before embarking on this journey.

Answer (score 0):

you have to fire up a new instance of the service with the new code. You need to then swithc users to the new service, typically via DNS tweaking

if you are running on AWS or azure they have tools that will hot switch to the new service for you, typically not via DNS but at a lower level so that it happens crisply

Comment: This is a cool idea, I apreciate your answer but basically it's would be so hard for me to acheive this as it's a game server. But I liked the idea maybe I will dive more into it. thank you again